# How do change the value of object inside the find query of javascript in parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

i try to change the value of object of find query of javascript in parse.com ,but it not   work plz help..

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>
<script>

Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        var AppToParse = Parse.Object.extend("AppToParse");
        var query = new Parse.Query(AppToParse);
        query.equalTo("status", true);
        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i];
                    document.write(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('number'));

                    results[i].save(null, {success: function(results[i]){
                        results[i].set("status", false);
                        results[i].save();}
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        }); 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: NEVER document.write anything after load

Comment: yes this was the mistake,thanx

Comment: Details please. What's not working? Any error messages? etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong you are trying to update the value "status" from true to false.

So to do that you just have to set the desired value to that object.

```
  Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    var AppToParse = Parse.Object.extend("AppToParse");
    var query = new Parse.Query(AppToParse);
    query.equalTo("status", true);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                document.write(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('number'));
                //set here new values as
                results[i].set("status", false);
                results[i].save();

            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    }); 
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a very similar issue and solved it with the help of this solution:
[Saving objects in query with Parse.com limited to first rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948465/saving-objects-in-query-with-parse-com-limited-to-first-rows)

In my situation, I was performing a set/save on each result and while it would appear the values were being updated properly, once the function was complete the database didn't reflect any of the changes.

Collecting all the objects in an array first and then using the Parse.Object.saveAll function to do a bulk save (again see solution above) solved it.